# unable to install graph-tool in windows 7

Tags: python, boost, windows-7, mingw, boost-python

I'd like to use [graph-tool](http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/) on windows 7, but I'm having trouble installing it.

All the requirements listed [here](http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/wiki/GraphToolDownload) are successfully installed. Python 2.7 is installed in `C:\python27`. Boost 1.49.0 was successfully compiled with mingw, installed in `C:\boost` and the `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable is pointing to it. Boost is compiled in debug and release mode and both static and dynamic.

---

Invoking `configure` from within MSyS leads to the following error.

```
configure: error:
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ============================================================================
```

---

Calling `configure LDFLAGS="-LC:/python27/libs"` fixed this error, but lead to the following error

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.38.0... configure: error: We could not detect the boo
st libraries (version 1.38 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still
 not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a
 PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then ch
eck your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.
de/boost for more documentation.
```

This is weird, since `BOOST_ROOT` is clearly defined (checked it with `printenv` command).

---

The next command I tried was `configure --with-boost="C:/boost" LDFLAGS="-LC:/python27/libs"`

```
checking for boostlib >= 1.38.0... yes
checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... no
configure: error: No usable boost::python found
```

Alright it detects boost, but It can't find boost::python. Due to its size I'm unable to post the `config.log` on stackoverflow but you can find it [here](http://pastebin.com/ApSJgkyB).

I'm really confused right now and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6):

I have zero experience with compiling graph-tool (or anything else) for windows, but the following part of your config.log stands out:

```
    configure:17224: checking whether the Boost::Python library is available
    configure:17254: g++ -c  -Wall -ftemplate-depth-150 -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O99 -fvisibility=default -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unknown-pragmas  -Ic:\python27\include conftest.cpp >&5
    conftest.cpp:32:36: fatal error: boost/python/module.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

Note how the boost path you passed is not being used! Try to pass CXXFLAGS="-IC:\boost\include" to configure as well.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this would help:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/
```

for windows path is different, try it yourself.